# Angular , how to handle when user click button or submit multiple times?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, mouseevent

How can I prevent users from submitting a form multiple times? My current issue right now is when the user clicked the submit button multiple times it will create multiple users. It should create a user only once and wait before creating another user.

Here is what I have:

```
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]="userStatus == 'USER_EXISTS_ON_CURRENT_ACCOUNT'" (click)="createUser()">Create
                        User</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
createUser() {
    this.accountService.create(this.modelForm.value).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.isInProgress = false;
      })
    ).subscribe({next: (res) => { this.notificationService.showSuccess('User has been created successfully.');
        this._router.navigate(['settings/user']);
      },
      error: (err) => {this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
        this.isInProgress = false;
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.isInProgress = false;
      },
    });
  }
```

Comment: Should the functionality be that it restricts user from clicking till the API responds with a value for the prior click event? Or just restrict the user from clicking the button again for some 'n' number of seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have slightly updated your code,

1 - We will have to create a User button in the template And

```
    <button #createUserBtn mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]="userStatus == 'USER_EXISTS_ON_CURRENT_ACCOUNT'"> CreateUser </button>
```

2 - Access Create User button in .ts file

```
@ViewChild('createUserBtn', {static:true}) button;
```

3 - Create variable `clicks$` to store click events

```
clicks$: Observable<any>;
```

4 - In ngOnInit: Initialize `clicks$` variable to listen click events

```
this.clicks$ = fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click');
```

5 - In ngOnInit: On every click event i.e from `click$` we will pass our event to [exhaustMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/exhaustMap)

> The beauty of exhaustMap is once the first (outer observable) event is triggered it will stop
> listening to events(Outer Observable) untill  it completes its inner observable

So in our case when the user clicks on the button the first time(event), the `exhaustMap` will stop listening to the button click events until it completes our API call `createUser()`. This API call observable we will handle using the `handleResponse()` method.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.clicks$ = fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click');
    
    const result$ = this.clicks$.pipe(
        tap(x => console.log('clicked.')),
        exhaustMap(ev => {
            console.log(`processing API call`);
            return this.createUser();
        })
    );
    
    result$.subscribe(this.handleResponse());
}
```

Create User API Call

```
createUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.accountService.create(this.modelForm.value).pipe(
      finalize(() => (this.isInProgress = false))
    );
  }
```

To handle response

```
handleResponse(): any {
    return {
      next: res => {
        this.notificationService.showSuccess('User has been created successfully.');
        this._router.navigate(['settings/user']);
      },
      error: err => {
        this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
        this.isInProgress = false;
      }
      complete: () => this.isInProgress = false;
    };
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-evzceu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

If you can't access button you can move ngOnit Code to `AfterViewInit`
Let me know if there is any error because i have not fully tested your code.

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click')
      .pipe(
        tap(x => console.log('clicked.')),
        exhaustMap(ev => {
          console.log(`processing API call`);
          return this.createUser();
        })
      )
      .pipe(tap(x => console.log('Api call completed....')))
      .subscribe(this.handleResponse());
  }
```

Comment: why is it triggering on initialization ? , it should only create user when button is clicked Sir

Comment: it is calling on page load

Comment: Check demo. Figure out what is difference. Else share your `oninit` code

Comment: If you share that scenario on stackBlitz, I can figure out the problem

Comment: it is triggering the this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.'); ,

Comment: it is triggering the this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.'); , on page Load

Comment: Share code. Because in demo that is not the case. If you would share code, My be i could figure out the problem.

Comment: I think the issue with your code Sir , is your putting the result$ on ngonit so be default it will execute the createUser even though there still no data from this.modelForm.value cause you are calling it on ngInit

Comment: it is working on your demo since you are not calling a real service or creating data , in real life scenario it wont work cause you are calling create user right on ngOnit\

Comment: the createUser should only be executed on button click

Comment: If what you think is right then replace code of `result$` with `result$.pipe(tap(x => console.log('calling api....'))).subscribe(this.handleResponse());` If it is really calling onInit it will show `calling api...` in console.log

Comment: You can move ngOnit logic to ngAfterViewInit, check above in updated answer. Check `console.logs` I have added console.logs at every stage

Comment: What was problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the functionality you want is that the user should be restricted from clicking the button again till the API responds with a value for the prior click event, you can do the following,

In your component.html file,

```
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]="isButtonDisabled()" (click)="createUser()">Create User </button>
```

In your component.ts file,

- Create a boolean type variable, with initial value set to false.
  `disableUserCreation: boolean = false;`
- Create the following function,

```
isButtonDisabled(): boolean {
    if (this.userStatus == 'USER_EXISTS_ON_CURRENT_ACCOUNT' || this.disableUserCreation) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then,

```
createUser() {
    this.disableUserCreation = true;
    this.accountService.create(this.modelForm.value).pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.isInProgress = false;
      })
    ).subscribe({next: (res) => { this.notificationService.showSuccess('User has been created successfully.');
        this._router.navigate(['settings/user']);
      },
      error: (err) => {this.notificationService.showError('Something went wrong, Try again later.');
        this.isInProgress = false;
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.isInProgress = false;
        this.disableUserCreation = false;
      },
    });
}
```